# How to detect invalid option value

Tags: perl, arguments, getopt

I have a perl script that is expected to parse the following:

prog -t xyz -p "a b" -cm xyz.cmd -co xyz.config

But I want it to error out when I enter

prog -t xyz -p a b -cm xyz.cmd -co xyz.config

(Because -p is followed by a and b without quotes).   I am using Getopt::Long to process the cmd line args.  How do I catch the above situation and error out?

Thanks!

Comment: In your second use case, `b` would be treated as a regular command line argument and would persist in `@ARGV`, so just check that `@ARGV` only has one element?

Comment: If `a` or `b` are expected to be other than strings, than you can use that fact, require integer (or float) intput for `-p`.  Other than that, you'll have a loose `b` in `@ARGV` after `Getopt::Long` is done with its part, you can check for it.  Or just parse and check the `-p` input.

Answer (score 7):

You could simply check if you're left with non-options.

```
use Getopt::Long qw( );

my ($opt_t, $opt_p, $opt_cm, $opt_co);

sub parse_args {
   Getopt::Long::Configure(qw( posix_default ));

   ($opt_t, $opt_p, $opt_cm, $opt_co) = ();

   Getopt::Long::GetOptions(
      'h|help|?' => \&help,
      't=s'  => \$opt_t,
      'p=s'  => \$opt_p,
      'cm=s' => \$opt_cm,
      'co=s' => \$opt_co,
   )
      or usage();

   @ARGV == 0
      or usage("Too many arguments.");
}

{
   parse_args();
   ...
}
```

Output (using the `usage` provided below):

```
$ ./prog -t xyz -p a b -cm xyz.cmd -co xyz.config
Too many arguments.
Try `prog --help' for more information.
```

---

As an aside, some recommendations for the implementation of `help` and `usage`:

```
use File::Basename qw( basename );

sub help {
   my $prog = basename($0);
   print("$prog [options]\n");
   print("$prog --help\n");
   print("\n");
   print("Options:\n");
   ...
   exit(0);
}

sub usage {
   my $prog = basename($0);
   if (my ($msg) = @_) {
      chomp($msg);
      warn("$msg\n");
   }

   warn("Try `$prog --help' for more information.\n");
   exit(1);
}
```

Comment: @ysth I think `require_order` is irrelevant for this problem.

Comment: @melpomene, It's not required, though it does stop parsing sooner with it. I always use `posix_default`. (Why would you want your new program to be non-standard?)

Comment: @ikegami Because none of the other programs on my machine (GNU utils) follow strict POSIX rules.

Comment: Thanks.   This addresses the issue I was facing.    Best wishes.

Comment: Awesome explanations champ